# Issue converting Date to Timestamp using Unix

Tags: unix

I have a `date.csv` file with different dates and I am not able to convert it into a time stamp.
e.g.

`date.csv` has the following dates:-

```
Mar 24 2014
Apr 1 2014
Aug 25 2014
```

I am trying to convert the above dates to:-

```
03/24/2014 00:00:00
04/01/2014 00:00:00
08/25/2014 00:00:00
```

i.e. in mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00 format, thereby storing the output in a new file i.e. `date1.csv`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `date`? Read the manpage. Is your csv a csv or just space delimited fields?

Comment: Do the dates appear in one column of the file - say column 3 - and you need some way to convert the date?  Are there any limitations on the tools that can be used?  For example, Perl has [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) to read and write CSV files, and [POSIX::strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX%3A%3Astrptime) and [POSIX::strftime](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#strftime).  Note that Text::CSV and POSIX::strptime may need to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GNU date utility to perform the conversion:

```
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:M:%S" -d "Mar 24 2014"
03/24/2014 00:00:00
```

The question doesn't specify what tools you can use, but this is a basic solution in Python that handles reading in the CSV file, converting the dates, and outputting it to another CSV file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
from datetime import datetime
import sys

DATE_COLUMN = 3 # Or whatever column has the date

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

with open(input_file) as i_f:
    reader = csv.reader(i_f)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as o_f:
        writer = csv.writer(o_f)
        for row in reader:
            date = datetime.strptime(row[DATE_COLUMN], "%h %d %Y")
            row[DATE_COLUMN] = date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:M:%S")
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Usage:

```
python csv_date_converter.py input_file output_file
```

Comment: How would you integrate mapping the relevant field of each line into the output?

Comment: You mean pull that out from the other fields in the CSV? You could use sed/awk, but I might suggest using a CSV library, like [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in the Python standard library.

Comment: Roughly, the data passed to the `date` command is one field in a CSV file, and you are therefore going to need to invoke the `date` command once per line of input, having extracted the date field from the line, and then rewrite the line with the substitute date value.  Your proposal maps one value - an important component of the whole task, but not the whole task.

Comment: I think the question is unclear (what qualifies as "using Unix"?) but I've outlined a more complete solution using Python + standard library modules that should be available on most unix-like systems.

Comment: +1 for the outline solution.  What happens if the script is passed no files?  Do the references to `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` cause trouble?  That's nitpicking though; it could be fixed by removing the square brackets around the file names in the synopsis, or by extra testing in the setup code.  It would arguably be more memory efficient (I think) to use `for row in list(reader):` rather than slurping the whole file into memory before writing anything.

Comment: Yes, it just blows up with an exception if `sys.argv[1]` or `sys.argv[2]` are missing. I'm assuming this is a quick-and-dirty script that would be used once (or a handful of times).

If you were going to be serious about providing a nicer interface, you could use the [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) or [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) libraries instead of reading directly from sys.argv.

It would definitely be more memory efficient to read and write simultaneously, but then your input and output files couldn't be the same file.

Comment: You should also start worrying about time zones. Which TZ the data comes from and what is your TZ variable set in your shell. 00:00:00 GMT would show up on a machine which is configured for CET either as 01:00:00 or 02:00:00 during DST. And for extra fun DST does not change at the same time everywhere in the world...eg US markets opening time in Europe is odd for a week in the spring and in the fall.

Comment: @bjmc:- Thank you for the reply and apologies for not replying to your queries. I am trying to do this with the help of unix shell script.. working on ksh. I cannot try your Python script but yes I did try out date function...

Comment: my dates.csv file has 3 entries i.e.
Mar 27 2014
Aug 24 2014
Apr 06 2014
These are 3 rows, separated by line feed delimiter.

I have not been able to use date function to convert the above dates to timestamps (for all the dates present in dates.csv file and in a iterative way).

I want this output to be added to a new file i.e. dates1.csv file and in the following format:-
'03/08/2014 00:00:00','08/24/2014 00:00:00','04/06/2014 00:00:00'